# xml nodes isn't handling an empty node

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2019 to parse out html as nodes. I've managed to strip out the html that interferes, but now I'm having a problem with an empty td node.

Here's a string I'm using to test (notice the `<td/>`):

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <td>Element</td>
        <td>20562</td>
        <td>20471</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Other</td>
         <td>No</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Other Unique Terms</td>
         <td/>
         <td>Of note:  blah blah. </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here's my T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
        (
               FieldName VARCHAR(MAX),
               OldValue VARCHAR(MAX),
               NewValue VARCHAR(MAX)
        )

DECLARE @html varchar(max), @html2 xml;

SET @html = '<table><tr><td>Element</td><td>20562</td><td>20471</td></tr><tr><td>Other</td><td>No</td><td>Yes</td></tr><tr><td>Other Unique Terms</td><td/><td>Of note:  blah blah. </td></tr></table>';

SET @html2 = CAST(@html as xml);

INSERT INTO @data
    SELECT
        n.value('(./td/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS FieldName,
        n.value('(./td/text())[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS OldValue,
        n.value('(./td/text())[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS NewValue
    FROM 
        @html2.nodes('/table/tr') AS nodes(n) 

SELECT *
FROM @data;
```

My results (the last row, the `OldValue` should be NULL and the `NewValue` should have the text):

```
FieldName              OldValue                 NewValue
---------------------------------------------------------
Element                20562                    20471
Other                  No                       Yes
Other Unique Terms     Of note:  blah blah.     NULL
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Drop the `/text()`, it will then not explicitly index on elements having text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
SELECT
    n.value('(./td/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as FieldName,
    n.value('(./td)[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as OldValue,
    n.value('(./td)[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as NewValue
FROM @html2.nodes('/tr') as nodes(n);
```

I removed the table. Since I knew the first column could not be empty, I left the text() in for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like so:

```
SELECT
    n.value('td[1]/text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS FieldName,
    n.value('td[2]/text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS OldValue,
    n.value('td[3]/text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS NewValue
FROM 
    @html2.nodes('/table/tr') AS nodes(n) ;
```

The idea in short:

- It looks, as if there are always three `<td>` elements.
- Their position specifies their meaning
- So we read the **first** `<td>` and pick its text.
- Then we read the **second** ... and so on...
- the final `[1]` tells the engine to pick the **first** text() node, which enforces the required *singleton* value.

Alternatively you might try this

```
SELECT
    n.value('td[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS FieldName,
    n.value('td[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS OldValue,
    n.value('td[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS NewValue
FROM 
    @html2.nodes('/table/tr') AS nodes(n)
```

In this case the empty element will be returned as an empty string and not as NULL.